# Proper nullable handling on a non-constrained generic type

Tags: c#

I have a generic API class like this:

```
public abstract class Command<T>
{
    public T result; // = default;

    public abstract void Execute();
}
```

Command is implemented by the user and can be of absolutely any datatype and should also allow for null result in case of reference types. Unfortunately this creates a problem with C# 8 with Nullable flag enabled.

e.g.

```
Command<int> -> default result is 0
Command<Foo> where Foo : class -> default result null
```

Another problem is my API is locked in C# 8.0, so I can not add nullable on unconstrained type. Is there any other workaround for this?

Only thing I've thought off is adding

```
protected abstract T DefaultResult { get; }
public T Result { get; protected set; } = DefaultResult;
```

and removing possibility of null altogether, but this would add much code bloat to the client having to implement every possible Command type with specific defaults and extend every reference type with DefaultType.

Comment: maybe another option is to wrap the result into a non-nullable wrapper somehow? But that would probably just move the same issue down the line.

Comment: Note that APIs should usually be targeted at a .Net version, not c# version. It should be perfectly possible to use c# 9 to target .net framework 4.8, even if some features will not be available due to lack of runtime support.

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I know of if to make a custom `Maybe<T>/Option<T>`-type. There should be plenty of articles on how to make one, and some implementations on github.

If you don't want a completely new generic type you can just make your command work in the same way as a maybe-type, i.e.

```
public abstract class Command<T>
{
    public T Value; 
    public bool HasValue; 
    public bool TryGet(out var value) ...
    // other convenience methods
```

Neither alternative is as nice as using built in language features, but if you cannot use them you have to find some kind of workaround.